# running a .py file from another Python script using os

Tags: python

Can someone give me a tip on how I can use `os` to run a different .py file from my python script? This code below works, but only because I specify the complete file path.

How can I modify the code to incorporate running `plots.py` from the same directory as my main script `app.py`? Im using Windows at the moment but hoping it can work on any operating system. Thanks

```
import os

os.system('py C:/Users/benb/Desktop/flaskEconServer/plots.py')
```

Comment: Have you tried just referring to it locally, doing `os.system('py plots.py')`?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do `from . import plots`?

Comment: Additional note: this isn't why the `os.system()` call exists. Look into using [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess), a standard-library module literally made for the purpose of executing other programs within a python program

Comment: What is the specific error the terminal gives you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the directory of the `app.py` file by using the following call in `app.py`

```
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

then join the file name you want

```
file_path = os.path.join(dir_path,'plot.py')
```

Finally your system call

```
os.system(f'py {file_path}') # if you're on 3.6 and above.
os.system('py %s' % file_path) # 3.5 and below
```

As others have said sub-processes and multi-threading may be better, but for your specific question this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute an arbitrary Python script as a separate process using the [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) function something like this:

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys

#py_filepath = 'C:/Users/benb/Desktop/flaskEconServer/plots.py'
py_filepath = 'plots_test.py'

args = '"%s" "%s" "%s"' % (sys.executable,                  # command
                           py_filepath,                     # argv[0]
                           os.path.basename(py_filepath))   # argv[1]

proc = subprocess.run(args)
print('returncode:', proc.returncode)
```

If you would like to communicate with the process while it's running, that can also be done, plus there are other `subprocess` functions, including the lower-level but very general `subprocess.Popen` class that support doing those kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

Python has built-in support for executing other scripts, without the need for the `os` module.

Try:

```py
from . import plots
```

If you want to execute it in an independent python process, look into the `multiprocessing` or `subprocess` modules.